# Laravel will not change mail service

Tags: laravel, swiftmailer

I have just copied a Laravel site from a third party server to my own (by cloning repo) and everything works except every time the mailer queue runs, it gets the following message:

```
Swift_TransportException: Expected response code 250 but got code "535", with message "535-5.7.8 Username and Password not accepted. 
Learn more at
535 5.7.8  https://support.google.com/mail/?p=BadCredentials b35sm5586532ede.2 - gsmtp
```

Now to me this looks like it is trying to connect with SMTP to gmail.com or google.com. And indeed it was initially set to use smtp.gmail.com, but I changed it so the .env file now has

```
MAIL_HOST=smtp.mailtrap.io
```

and logging the value of

```
env('MAIL_HOST')
```

prints the Mailtrap.io address. I've run

```
php artisan config:clear
```

(but it does look from the above the the environment IS getting set).

I have grepped for any reference to smtp.gmail in the source tree to see if there is some evil override somewhere - nothing.

Any ideas where else I could look or what I could log to debug this further?

Note: I have not rebooted the server, just in case it fixes the issue and I end up none the wiser. This kind of change should not require a reboot, I hope.

Comment: First place I would check would be config/mailer.php. As for the rebooting issues, only one I've experienced so far has been with composer autoload. Also, just in case, make sure that its the .env you are editing and not some example file.

Comment: Thx. Seems to be the right .env though, as I do see the new values when printing from e.g. index.php. `config/mail.php` just seems to use the env() values, no overrides there.

Answer (score 2):

Solved. I found that the queue worker process (running under systemd) had cached the code.

https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/queues#queue-workers-and-deployment

```
sudo php artisan queue:restart
```

...fixed it.